# -enter-active and -leave-active classes doesn't appear while toggle-in Vue event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

For some reason it is impossible to make transition effect where the -enter-active and -leave-active  appears with a default timeout in de html code of my webpack/vue-loader application.

I've copy/pasted the below code from the [vue-guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) in my webproject after dealing with some problems with a lack of animation. Even this simple example below isn't working at all.

Does anyone else encounters this problem?

**index.html**

```
  <div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
  </div>
```

**My main.js file:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

**I've resolved the above code by adding css class fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active **

However, the same principle does still not work in my image slider which I've created in a Vue.component. The code looks something like this.

```
var dataHome = { show: true,
                 currentNumber: 1,
                 images: ['image1.jpg',
                          'image2.jpg',
                          'image3.jpg',
                          'image4.jpg',
                          'image5.jpg']
                 }

const Home = {
  template: `<div class="box-container">
              <p><a @click="prev">Previous</a> || <a @click="next">Next</a></p>
              <transition name="fade">
                <div id="demo" v-if="show">
                  <img :src="images[Math.abs(currentNumber) % images.length]"/>
                </div>
              </transition>
            </div>`,
  data: function () {
    return dataHome  //dataset with images
  },
  methods: {
    next: function () {
      this.currentNumber += 1;
      this.show = true;
    },
    prev: function () {
      this.currentNumber -= 1;
      this.show = true;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: did you declare the css classes?

Comment: I resolved it by adding css classes, tnx! But look above. Now I want to try to use transition in my Vue.component, for adding a fade effect while clicking through the slider. With or without the fade css class, transition not seem to work.

Comment: You didn't mention `fade-enter` in your edit to the question, which should be required for the fade to work (setting an initial opacity of 0), as described in the guide. Did you include it?

Comment: Yes I did as follow: .fade-transition {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave {
  opacity: 0;
  visib